# PhpStorm: strange indicator above the scrollbar

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

[image: strange indicator]

I'm new to PhpStorm, and maybe I'm missing something, but I can't figure out, what is this blue line above the scrollbar? I've tried hard. How is it called, how can I manage or disable it? Sorry for your time.

Comment: usually above the scrollbar displaying error links

Comment: I also tried everything in the inspections settings, disabling enabling all indicators. I've tried to delete all the plugins and to reinstall phpstorm.

Comment: try open empty file or delete code

Comment: Settings - Editor - General. Inside general settings there is block "Other". And it was called "Highlight modified lines in gutter ".

Comment: pleas disable metherial UI plugin and attach a screenshot without it

Comment: this happens with and without material ui plugin, since it is affected by editor  settings, not general theme settings(GUI, LAF). I also thought that it is caused by third party plugins, so I deleted them all, and nothing changed. I still can't find where I can change the color of this line, cause there is no such option in "editor - color scheme -  VCS". At least I can enable and disable it.